# Find the supremum and infimum of $B = \{g(x)=x,g(x)=x^2\}$ on the partially ordered set $Y=\Bbb R^{[0,2]}$ by pointwise relation.

Tags: real-analysis, relations

Find the supremum and infimum of $B=\{g(x)=x,g(x)=x^2\}$ on the partially ordered set $Y=\Bbb R^{[0,2]}$ (set of all functions from $[0,2]$ to $\Bbb R$) by pointwise relation.

**Edit:**
**Definition.** A set $X = \Bbb R^2$ which is partially ordered set by pointwise relation is defined by
\begin{equation*}
x \le y \iff x_1 \le y_1 \quad \text{and} \quad x_2 \le y_2, \forall x=(x_1,y_1),y=(y_1,y_2) \in X.
\end{equation*}

Could I consider the set $B$ above as the union of two sets $P$ and $Q$, where $P=\{(x,x):x \in [0,2]\}$ and $Q=\{(x,x^2):x\in [0,2]\}$? If yes, then I can use the supremum property: $\sup\{P,Q\} = \sup\{\sup P, \sup Q\}$.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, that
$x^2 \leq x$ for $x\in [0,1]$ and
$x \leq x^2$ for $x\in (1,2]$.
It is thus clear, that the function
$$h_1(x) = \begin{cases} x &\text{ for $x \in [0,1]$} \\
                       x^2 & \text{ for $x \in (1,2]$}
          \end{cases}$$
is an upper bound for the set $B$. It is in fact the least upper bound (why?), hence $h_1$ is the supremum. By similar arguments it can be seen that
$$h_2(x) = \begin{cases} x^2 &\text{ for $x \in [0,1]$} \\
                       x & \text{ for $x \in (1,2]$}
          \end{cases}$$
is the infimum.

Regarding your own approach: I don't think it really makes sense to do it the way you describe it. Note, that the set $P=\{(x,x) \: | \: x \in [0,2]\}$ is not a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{[0,2]}$, but rather a subset of $[0,2]\times \mathbb{R}$, and it thus not clear how $\sup (P)$ should be interpreted (it would depend on which partial ordering you equip $[0,2]\times \mathbb{R}$ with). We can however write the set $B$ as a union in the obvious way $\{f(x)=x,g(x)=x^2\} = \{f(x)=x\} \cup \{g(x)=x^2\}$, which allows us to write the supremum as $\sup(B) = \sup(\sup\{f(x)=x\},\sup\{g(x)=x^2\})$, which will lead us nowhere, since $\sup(\{f(x)=x\}) = f$ and $\sup(\{g(x)=x^2\})=g$.

Comment: I have add the definition of the pointwise relation, Sir.

Comment: Based on your explanation above, then $\sup B = fg$, isn't it?

Comment: Also, what about the infimum, Sir? Is $h_2(x)$ be the infimum of $B$?

Comment: Your definition of pointwise relation assumes the set $X$ to consist of tuples $(x_1,x_2)$, but a function is not a tuple. The usual definition of a pointwise relation on $\mathbb{R}^{[0,2]}$ would be $f\leq g \Leftrightarrow (\forall x \in [0,2] \: : f(x) \leq g(x))$. An upper bound for $\{f,g\}$ would thus be a function $h$ satisfying $f(x)\leq h(x)$ and $g(x)\leq h(x)$ for all $x\in [0,2]$.

.... I cannot see any reasoning behind $\sup B = fg$....

The infimum is quite similar to the supremum (i even wrote what it is in my answer).

Comment: My bad, Sir. I mean, the supremum of $B$ is $\sup\{f,g\}$, isn't it? And it is equal to $h$ which was defined in your answer above?

Comment: I have edited my post, Sir. I mean, the set $X$ in the definition is $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Yes the supremum of $B$ is $\sup\{f,g\}$ (i just renamed one of the functions $f$ to avoid having two different functions named $g$). The supremum and infimum are in my answer. Ok, you have added the definition of pointwise relation on $\mathbb{R}^2$, however the question is still about pointwise relations on $\mathbb{R}^{[0,2]}$. If you take the supremum over a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ you will get an element of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and not an element of $\mathbb{R}^{[0,2]}$.

Comment: OK, Sir. I got the point right now. Thanks a lot, Sir.